# MCE as a servcie?

Tags: windows-media-center

Putting together a MCE machine. This is more a curiosity issue than anything but does MCE run as a Windows service? Will it record scheduled programs if no one is logged on or it isn't running in the UI?

Specifically talking about Win7 MCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Some of the services involved are:

- Windows Media Center Extender Service
- Windows Media Center Receiver Service
- Windows Media Center Scheduler Service
- Windows Media Center Service Launcher